# How to convert DirectDraw Surface (DDS) files to JPG

Tags: delphi, dds-format

I'm currently working on a project that requires users to be able to view DDS files in my application, but I haven't been able to find a way to either  directly display DDS files or convert DDS files to JPG. ImageMagick does this but as far as I understand it requires a command line tool and a host of dll files to be distributed with my application and I would rather avoid that if possible. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddds/dx-graphics-dds-pguide ?

Comment: DDS = DirectDraw Surface. If your target audience wants DDS then they most likely have DirectX installed, which you can use (https://www.delphipraxis.net/1387491-post10.html and others; RedeemerGfx seems promising - register to download).

Comment: @AmigoJack Thank you, I was able to load a DDS file into a TImage32 component easily using RedeemerGfx with this one line:
Image32.Bitmap.Assign(PNGToBMP(LoadDXT5(Filename)));